# Show/Hide DataGrid columns based on List content

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, show-hide

I'm writing a `WPF` application to display log files generated within a large system, of which this will be a part. Log files are `.CSV` files, and will have a predefined number of columns. However, there are 'sub-types' hidden within these files. Let me elaborate.

For brevity, let's say my files have 4 columns, namely:

> LineNum, Data1, Data2, Data3

But here's the catch. Our `Type1` log files will have data pertaining to `LineNum, Data1, and Data2`, while our `Type2` log files will have data pertaining to `LineNum, Data1, and Data3`. Keep in mind that this is just one example, I actually have more than 4 columns, and there's about 20 different combinations. Following are two examples of each type of logs.

### Type1

> 1,Data1A,Data2A,,
>
> 2,Data1B,Data2B,,
>
> 3,Data1C,Data2C,,

### Type2

> 1,Data1A,,Data3A,
>
> 2,Data1B,,Data3B,
>
> 3,Data1C,,Data3C,

As I said before, my actual files have a large number of columns (70+), but each type will have data pertaining to only a handful of columns. I have absolutely no control over this as it's part of an older larger system that's already in place. Now I would like for my application to read these files, but display only the columns that have data in them.

Luckily, within the larger system, there's a set of 'system' files that indicate which type of files have data in which columns. So, the `sys` file of `Type1` will look like this:

> 1, 1, 1, 0

A `1` indicates that all but 3rd column (`Data3`) will have data. And the `sys` file of `Type2` will look like this:

> 1, 1, 0, 1

Indicating that all but `Data2` will be available.

Now, the user selects by a file select dialog which type of file to display. When they do, I want the application to figure out which type it is, and accordingly display only the applicable columns. Here's a sample application that illustrates the application.

Two `Model` classes I use:

```
public class LogDataSet
{
    public List<LogData> LogData { get; set; }
    public List<bool> DisplayColumns { get; set; }
}

public class LogData
{
    public int LineNum { get; set; }
    public string Data1 { get; set; }
    public string Data2 { get; set; }
    public string Data3 { get; set; }
}
```

The `DisplayColumsn` list essentially tells you which columns should be displayed. It should be easy to understand the rest by looking at the code below. I have two sample `Button` events to mimic user selecting different log types. At the time of reading, I also read the correct `sys` file type, and display data.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private LogDataSet _logDataSet;
    public LogDataSet LogDataSet
    {
        get { return _logDataSet; }
        set { _logDataSet = value; OnPropertyChanged("LogDataSet"); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void BtnType1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var type1logs = new List<LogData>
        {
            new LogData() { LineNum = 1, Data1 = "Data1A", Data2 = "Data2A" },
            new LogData() { LineNum = 2, Data1 = "Data1B", Data2 = "Data2B" },
            new LogData() { LineNum = 3, Data1 = "Data1C", Data2 = "Data2C" }
        };
        LogDataSet = new LogDataSet() { LogData = type1logs };
        LogDataSet.DisplayColumns = ReadSysFiles("Type1.sys");

    }

    private void BtnType2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var type2logs = new List<LogData>
        {
            new LogData() { LineNum = 1, Data1 = "Data1A", Data3 = "Data3A" },
            new LogData() { LineNum = 2, Data1 = "Data1B", Data3 = "Data3B" },
            new LogData() { LineNum = 3, Data1 = "Data1C", Data3 = "Data3C" }
        };
        LogDataSet = new LogDataSet() { LogData = type2logs };
        LogDataSet.DisplayColumns = ReadSysFiles("Type2.sys");
    }

    public static List<bool> ReadSysFiles(string path)
    {
        var data = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList()[0];
        var parts = data.Split(',');
        var display = new List<bool>();
        foreach (var item in parts)
        {
            display.Add(item == "1" ? true : false);
        }
        return display;
    }
}
```

And my simple `XAML` here:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
              Name="DgLogs" Margin="8" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding LogDataSet.LogData}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Line #" Binding="{Binding LineNum}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data1" Binding="{Binding Data1}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data2" Binding="{Binding Data2}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data3" Binding="{Binding Data3}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button x:Name="BtnType1" Content="Type 1" 
            Width="100" Height="28" Margin="4, 4, 4, 8" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
            Click="BtnType1_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="BtnType2" Content="Type 2" 
            Width="100" Height="28" Margin="4, 4, 4, 8" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
            Click="BtnType2_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

This will obviously display all 4 columns, with empty cells in columns that don't have data per the file type. But how would I go about *hiding* those columns, based on my `bool` list `DisplayColumns`? I see a lot of SO posts showing how to do something like this based on another control etc, but not how to bind to an index of a list.

### Edit

I'd be open to other creative solutions as well, and I don't necessarily have to read the `sys` files and use `DisplayColumns` list. It's the approach I took, but as long as the job gets done, I can go another path.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to hide those columns, you could easily do it after the grid has initialized.

```
<DataGrid Name="DgLogs" Initialized="DgLogs_OnInitialized">
```

You have the two following methods to do that:

```
private void DgLogs_OnInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!(sender is DataGrid grid)) return;

    //Column with index 1 will be hidden.
    grid.Columns[1].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

    //Column with header = Data2 will be hidden
    var column = grid.Columns.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Header.Equals("Data2"));
    column.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

**EDIT**

You could also use binding and use a Converter to find which columns to hide:

```
    <DataGrid Name="DgLogs" Margin="8" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" Initialized="DgLogs_OnInitialized">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <myProject:MyHeaderToVisibilityConverter x:Key="MyHeaderToVisibilityConverter"/>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Line #" Binding="{Binding LineNum}" Visibility="{Binding Path=Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},  Converter={StaticResource MyHeaderToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data1" Binding="{Binding Data1}" Visibility="{Binding Path=Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},  Converter={StaticResource MyHeaderToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data2" Binding="{Binding Data2}" Visibility="{Binding Path=Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},  Converter={StaticResource MyHeaderToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data3" Binding="{Binding Data3}" Visibility="{Binding Path=Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},  Converter={StaticResource MyHeaderToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Converter:

```
public class MyHeaderToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //Find your settings for each header here.
        //and compare below with the results
        switch (value?.ToString())
        {
            case "Line #":
                return Visibility.Visible;
            case "Data1":
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            default:
                return Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't quite solve my problem. As I stated, there are different types of files, and I'll know the type only when user selects the file. I would like to use the `bool` list I have, or a solution that would facilitate not hardcoding.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the `PropertyChanged` event for the `LogDataSet` property in the view:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    PropertyChanged += MainWindow_PropertyChanged;
    DataContext = this;
}

private void MainWindow_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(LogDataSet))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < DgLogs.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            DgLogs.Columns[i].Visibility = LogDataSet.DisplayColumns[i] ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

Just make sure that the `DisplayColumns` property is initialized when you set the `LogDataSet` property, i.e. set it in the initializer and not afterwards:

```
private void BtnType1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var type1logs = new List<LogData>
    {
        new LogData() { LineNum = 1, Data1 = "Data1A", Data2 = "Data2A" },
        new LogData() { LineNum = 2, Data1 = "Data1B", Data2 = "Data2B" },
        new LogData() { LineNum = 3, Data1 = "Data1C", Data2 = "Data2C" }
    };
    LogDataSet = new LogDataSet() { LogData = type1logs, DisplayColumns = ReadSysFiles("Type1.sys") };
}

private void BtnType2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var type2logs = new List<LogData>
    {
        new LogData() { LineNum = 1, Data1 = "Data1A", Data3 = "Data3A" },
        new LogData() { LineNum = 2, Data1 = "Data1B", Data3 = "Data3B" },
        new LogData() { LineNum = 3, Data1 = "Data1C", Data3 = "Data3C" }
    };
    LogDataSet = new LogDataSet() { LogData = type2logs, DisplayColumns = ReadSysFiles("Type2.sys") };
}
```

Comment: It's my bad that I forgot to mention that I use the `MVVM` pattern in my application, so I'd rather not access the datagrid from my `ViewModel`, and I'd rather not do the column hiding in my `View` (I don't have access to the `LogDataSet` in my `View` anyway).

Comment: Wrong. If you are using MVVM you *should* hide the columns in the view. Everything else would break the pattern. A view model doesn't know anything about any columns in the view. It exposes the `DisplayColumns` collection but it's up to the view to hide the columns. So you should handle the `PropertyChanged` event in the view.